# Experiencing random timeout between Cloud Run and Cloud SQL using VPC Connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I am looking to deploy a Cloud Run service that has the following connections settings:

Cloud SQL Connections: 1 cloud sql instance

VPC: Network: Serverless VPC Access Connector - Route all traffic through the VPC connector

I use the following command to deploy my cloud run from a yaml file:

```
gcloud run services replace cloudrun.yaml --platform managed --region us-east1 --project my-project --format json
```

The issue that I am running into is about 75% of the time creating a new service fails with the error:

```
Cloud SQL connection failed. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run for additional details: connection to Cloud SQL instance at <public-ip>:3307 failed: timed out after 10s
```

Note: All resources (Cloud Run, VPC, VPC Access Connector, Cloud SQL, NAT Gateway) are in us-east1. Anything that can be associated with a VPC is associated with the same VPC.

What I've found is that setting the Serverless Access Connector to `Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector` allows Cloud SQL to connect properly, but unfortunately, does not work for my application use case.

Otherwise, it is seemingly at random where I can use the exact same yaml file where only the name of the service being created is changed and 25% of the time it creates the service successfully with no errors, but a vast majority of the time I get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a known combination of features that does not work: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#sql-with-vpc-egress

Comment: Gold. This was very helpful and is also applicable to GAE Standard.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Exactly my problem. i was going nuts trying to understand what is going on. Idk why it worked for weeks for me without issues and started to fail just recently. I need root all traffic to VPC so I switched to using private IP connection. It needs some additional client cert configuration but works pretty good now. Thanks again.

Comment: I will be interested to see if this works with the new direct VPC egress option that is currently in preview (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/vpc-direct-vpc). I haven't had a chance to test it yet.